# Joomla voting doesn't save

Tags: joomla

I have a problem I cant figure out. When I started the website the voting system worked... but now many hours later it doesn't save the vote anymore.

I hope some of you have tried the same or have an idea about what can be wrong.

You can see a post on my site here: http://secretinvizimals.com/index.php/10-invizimals-the-lost-tribes/39-lizard-queen

BR

Comment: What voting system are you using?

Comment: could it be that voting works only if you're logged in ? just a thought...

Comment: Just the default voting system

Answer (score 1):

Rather hard to tell only by looking at it and not having access to the code, so these are the only things I can suggest.

1. Ensure you have the latest Joomla version (2.5.6)
2. Switch to the default Joomla template and try voting again.
3. Install JDump to see if its a PHP related problem.
4. Install a fresh copy of Joomla and your template on a subdomain and after each extension you install, test the vote.

Comment: I have testet number 1 and 2 and that didn't help me. But I don't know how to use JDump... can you help me?